# Getter and Setter in checkbox angular

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have two pages, namely "view all" and "filter page".

On the filter page I have a checkbox list, when I click the "view all" button it will display the data according to the filter that was checked, and this is going well.

I want to make a checkbox that if after I click the button "view all", the checkbox value that is checked remains in the list.

I think there must be a setter and getter in the checkbox , but I am confused how to make it...

What I have created now is when I click show all, after displaying the data according to the checked list and I enter the list page, the list is empty, nothing is checked.

**filterpage.html**

```
<li *ngFor="let source of sourcesList">{{ source.sourceName }}<ion-checkbox class="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="source.checked" ></ion-checkbox></li>
```

to get the value as checked I use this code in .ts

```
 for(let item of this.sourcesList){
        if(item.checked == true){
          params = item.sourceName;
        }
      }
```

but how to do it so that when it displays the filter list again, it will be checked according to the previous tick a.k.a (not refreshed)??